# send user registeration mail in html format

Tags: users, theming, emails

I want to send any email of my site in HTML format, I install `smtp , mimemail and mailsystem` modules, and `smpt` configured correctly and test it(I check `Allow to send e-mails formated as Html`), also this is a snapshot of Mailsystem settings
[image] 
,also in Mimemail settings I set `E-mail format` in **FULL HTML** format,also I create `mimemail-message.tpl.php` in theme folder (and cleared cache).

it seems everything is ok,but when a user register in site, email not send in html format and is only plain text.

**How can I send any user email (registertion,canceling,approved,suspending ,...) in HTML format?**

Comment: Checkout HTML Mail module. It works well with smtp module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using PHPMailer module. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer

It is used to send HTML emails with Mime Mail.